# Ionic runtime error cannot read property "toLowerCase" of null

Tags: ionic-framework, runtime

I am trying to view an app via "ionic serve" but I get this error. I have looked at other subjects but have never seen a runtime error. I tried all of their solutions but I would still have the same error page. Here is what I see:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQi3o.jpg]

And to be honest, I am not the coder of this app, but I have bought it from a store. But, I know some here and there. If there is a simple solution to fix this, that would be amazing!

The first error link is pointing to here:

```
_this.initialData();
var operating_system = '';
var admob = {};
if (_this.device.platform.toLowerCase() == 'android') {
     operating_system = 'android';
     admob = {
         banner: settings['admob_android_banner'],
         interstitial: settings['admob_android_interstitial']
     };
 }
```

The second error link is pointing me to here:

```
SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub = function (fn, value) {
    try {
        fn.call(this._context, value);
    }
    catch (err) {
        this.unsubscribe();
        throw err;
    }
};
```

The third error is pointing to here:

```
SafeSubscriber.prototype.next = function (value) {
    if (!this.isStopped && this._next) {
        var _parentSubscriber = this._parentSubscriber;
        if (!_parentSubscriber.syncErrorThrowable) {
            this.__tryOrUnsub(this._next, value);
        }
        else if (this.__tryOrSetError(_parentSubscriber, this._next, value)) {
            this.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
```

The fourth error is pointing to here:

```
Subscriber.prototype._next = function (value) {
    this.destination.next(value);
};
```

The fifth error is pointing to here:

```
var /** @type {?} */ response = new Response(responseOptions);
    response.ok = isSuccess(status);
        if (response.ok) {
            responseObserver.next(response);
            // TODO(gdi2290): defer complete if array buffer until done
            responseObserver.complete();
            return;
        }
```

Here is the code I get in cmd:

```html
C:\Users\xx-nj\Desktop\DukhanApp\DukhanColor>ionic serve
Starting app-scripts server: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 --nobrowser -
Ctrl+C to cancel
[20:02:52]  watch started ...
[20:02:52]  build dev started ...
[20:02:53]  clean started ...
[20:02:53]  clean finished in 3 ms
[20:02:53]  copy started ...
[20:02:53]  deeplinks started ...
[20:02:53]  deeplinks finished in 573 ms
[20:02:53]  transpile started ...
[20:03:01]  transpile finished in 7.70 s
[20:03:01]  preprocess started ...
[20:03:01]  preprocess finished in 1 ms
[20:03:01]  webpack started ...
[20:03:01]  copy finished in 8.80 s
[20:03:09]  webpack finished in 8.01 s
[20:03:09]  sass started ...
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.
[20:03:13]  sass finished in 3.39 s
[20:03:13]  postprocess started ...
[20:03:13]  postprocess finished in 14 ms
[20:03:13]  lint started ...
[20:03:13]  build dev finished in 20.14 s
[20:03:13]  watch ready in 20.44 s
[20:03:13]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/

[OK] Development server running!
     Local: http://localhost:8100
     External: http://192.168.8.111:8100
     DevApp: celltore_ionic3@8100 on NajmLaptop

[20:03:23]  tslint: C:/Users/xx-nj/Desktop/DukhanApp/DukhanColor/src/pages/contactus/contactus.ts, line: 124
            'marker' is declared but never used.

     L123:  let map = new google.maps.Map(element, mapOptions);
     L124:  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     L125:    title: this.textStatic['cellstore_contact_us_title'],

[20:03:23]  tslint: ...s/xx-nj/Desktop/DukhanApp/DukhanColor/src/pages/detailcategory/detailcategory.ts, line: 138
            Duplicate variable: 'filter'

     L138:  for (var filter in this.filter['valueCustom']) {
     L139:      let attr = this.filter['value'][filter];

[20:03:23]  tslint: ...s/xx-nj/Desktop/DukhanApp/DukhanColor/src/pages/detailcategory/detailcategory.ts, line: 140
            Duplicate variable: 'option'

     L139:  let attr = this.filter['value'][filter];
     L140:  if (attr && Object.keys(attr).length > 0) for (var option in attr) {
     L141:                  if(option != 'select' && attr[option]) {

[20:03:23]  tslint: C:/Users/xx-nj/Desktop/DukhanApp/DukhanColor/src/pages/brand/brand.ts, line: 121
            Duplicate variable: 'filter'

     L121:  for (var filter in this.filter['valueCustom']) {
     L122:      let attr = this.filter['value'][filter];

[20:03:23]  tslint: C:/Users/xx-nj/Desktop/DukhanApp/DukhanColor/src/pages/brand/brand.ts, line: 123
            Duplicate variable: 'option'

     L122:  let attr = this.filter['value'][filter];
     L123:  if (attr && Object.keys(attr).length > 0) for (var option in attr) {
     L124:      if(option != 'select' && attr[option]) {

[20:03:23]  tslint: C:/Users/xx-nj/Desktop/DukhanApp/DukhanColor/src/pages/home/home.ts, line: 300
            Duplicate variable: 'diff'

     L299:  element[i]["due_date"] = false;
     L300:  var diff = (start.getTime() - today.getTime()) / 1000;
     L301:  element[i]['time_diff'] = Math.floor(diff);

[20:03:23]  tslint: C:/Users/xx-nj/Desktop/DukhanApp/DukhanColor/src/pages/home/home.ts, line: 165
            'remaining_time' is declared but never used.

     L164:  ngOnInit() {
     L165:      var remaining_time = setInterval(() => {
     L166:          if (this.navCtrl.getActive().component.name == "HomePage") {

[20:03:23]  tslint: C:/Users/xx-nj/Desktop/DukhanApp/DukhanColor/src/pages/search/search.ts, line: 213
            Duplicate variable: 'filter'

     L213:  for (var filter in this.filter['valueCustom']) {
     L214:      let attr = this.filter['value'][filter];

[20:03:23]  tslint: C:/Users/xx-nj/Desktop/DukhanApp/DukhanColor/src/pages/search/search.ts, line: 215
            Duplicate variable: 'option'

     L214:  let attr = this.filter['value'][filter];
     L215:  if (attr && Object.keys(attr).length > 0) for (var option in attr) {
     L216:      if(option != 'select' && attr[option]) {

[20:03:23]  lint finished in 10.05 s
```

Comment: Without any code, it is super difficult to find your error.

Comment: should i put every code of each line in the mentioned files?

Comment: Maybe a minimal context of where `toLowerCase()` is used.

Comment: I have added some of codes the error is pointing to

Answer (score 0):

It seems that platform is not returned properly and that's why it's null.

You didn't include your constructor so i have no idea how your constructor looks like, but the following code snippet is returning platform name properly using the [Device plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device/) you're using in your code.

```
import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device';

constructor(private device: Device) {}

......

if(this.device.platform.toLowerCase()=='android'){
    // Your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you're running ionic serve on web and the cordova platform isn't available there. Ionic Native returns {} when a property doesn't exist (when cordova isn't available), and it throws a console warning for developer assistance.
When one try to retrieve data from {} object then it will return null.
Please try adding below code:

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

//add it in constructor as follows:
constructor( public platform: Platform){

}
//add platform check
if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
   //add your code here
}else{
   console.log("Plugin not supported on web");
}
```

Comment: Hi @Najm AlDekhel, you have to add this code in the page, where you have checked the platform in your code.